# Storing and using images in my app to Parse

Tags: ios, image, parse-platform, backend

I recently uploaded my iOS quiz app to the Apple's app store but the file size is fairly large (150 MB) and would like to reduce this size drastically.  I believe the majority of the file size is coming from my images, I have over 500 jpg images in my app.  I recently incorporated Parse into my app in hopes of storing the files there.  Problem is, I am having some difficulty figuring out how to store and use the images from my app to Parse.  The basic setup of my App is like this:

I have two folders containing all the jpg images for my app.  They are saved to my project in the folders named "Newschool" and "Oldschool"

[image]

I then have two .plist files which contain all the questions and answers for my app.

[image]

Here is an example of one of the question and answer from the Oldschool.plist:

[image]

The user is shown the jpg image "PervisEllison.jpg" which is stored in the "Oldschool" folder.

So what would I need to do to move all my images from my App to Parse and code it so my App draws the image from Parse instead of the jpgs in the folders?  I'm sure I need to change some coding but don't know what.  I played around a little bit in Parse by adding rows and columns but have no clue what I'm dong..

I apologize ahead of time for my ignorance as I am still learning programming and know nothing of Backend as a service.  Thank you!

Comment: First things first. It would be more than beneficial to know what language your coding in because parse is cross platform. Secondly, there is a plethora of education material on the web (Parse.com for starters, and even Stackoverflow) does none of those materials help you? I could probably provide links to you to numerous questions already answered on here if you can narrow it down to what your particular issue is or where your stuck on.

Comment: Thanks soulshined that would be great.  My app is coded in Obj-C.  I guess I just want a general outline on how to approach this, as I never dealt with BaaS.

Comment: You should go on Parse.com and help yourself first. Read documentation because that will be your best friend with Parse. They are awesome, well-documented, and they have great tutorials. If you can't do it yourself then I am here to help, but you need to put some effort in the process. SO is not the place to have people code for you, but to help you with code related issues you have. Besides you don't learn that way anyways when it's handed to you You should start with `PFFile` https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files

Comment: In addition to what soulshined has mentioned, you may want to look specifically at the Anypic tutorial. It is a newsfeed-style iOS app (objective-c) which heavily uses images. https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

Comment: I'd like to point out that while using a backend to store your image files will drastically decrease your app size, you'll add the dependency that you need the internet for the app to work.

Comment: While we're throwing out pointers here, make sure you're thoroughly compressing your images. Assuming your app is only 15-20MB in size, 500 compressed images sized for mobile applications should not be taking up 130MB.

Comment: ok, so i decided to compress all the images I have in my app and was able to get the file size down from 148 to 87 MB!  Is there any other tips or advice you guys have to further lower the file size?  I feel like there are a lot of unnecessary stuff that i can rid of.